# How to consume here.com's REST api service

Tags: javascript, php, rest, curl, soap

Has anyone tried using here.com's rest api?
I'm trying to run an example request, but nothing happens. I'm new to REST, so I'm clueless about the problem. If the $url is plugged directly into the browsers address text box, the image is displayed, but my curl function in the code below does not retrieve anything, or so it seems.

```
$url = "http://image.maps.cit.api.here.com/mia/1.6/route?app_id=redacted&app_code=redacted&r0=52.5338,13.2966,52.538361,13.325329&r1=52.540867,13.262444,52.536691,13.264561,52.529172,13.268337,52.528337,13.273144,52.52583,13.27898,52.518728,13.279667&m0=52.5338,13.2966,52.538361,13.325329&m1=52.540867,13.262444,52.518728,13.279667&lc0=440000ff&sc0=440000ff&lw0=6&lc1=44ff00ff&sc1=44ff00ff&lw1=3";

$ch = curl_init($url);
$options = array(
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20 ,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
           );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($response);
echo "response: <br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "result: <br> " . $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Are you getting error messages? Have you tried to do any debugging?

Comment: No error messages. Just blank. Debugging runs the code normally..

Comment: I get a 401 code on adressing to the url. Did you already authenticate and have permission on requesting?

Comment: I did. Stackoverflow won't let me post my appid and appcode so you got that error.. but If I could get that error show in the curl response that would already mean it's working.. The problem may be that I may be using GET instead of POST.. I still don't know which is default

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the end.. This is a working sample of using the here.com REST api that I'm posting so that anyone who is in the same situation may have a look at it. The problem was that the construction of the query string was incorrect as I just copied and pasted it from the browser. If anybody comes across the same problem, I recommend taking a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image/topics/request-constructing.html)..

```
$base_url = 'http://image.maps.cit.api.here.com'; 
$path = '/mia/1.6/';
$resource = 'route';    // type of service... this should change if you want something else

$query_string = array(
    'app_id'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  //your app id
    'app_code'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  // your app code
    'r0'        => '52.540867,13.262444,52.536691,13.264561,52.529172,13.268337,52.528337,13.273144,52.52583,13.27898,52.518728,13.279667', // coords for the route
    'lw'        => '4',   // line width
    'lc'        => '00ff00',  // line color
);

$url = $base_url . $path.$resource . '?' . http_build_query($query_string);
$img_file = './img/test_img2.jpg';  // save image here

$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen($img_file, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

?>

<img src='<?php echo $img_file;?>'>
```